# When is javascript executed in relation to a DOM change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a code like this:

```
...
<script>
function myfunction(result) {
    $(".dyn").prop("innerHTML",result);
}
</script>
...
<table class="dyn">
</table>
<script>
    $.post('some_ajax_page',some_value,myfunction);
    $(".myeditable").on(blur,myfunction2);
</script>
...
```

The POST executes correctly and gets the content of the table, which is displayed correctly, and it is like this:

```
...
<tr><td class="myeditable">...</td></tr>
...
```

But the TD doesn't have a listener set for blur, even when the listener intends to be set after the POST has returned and its function executed.

Why doesn't the listener get set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Or, in this case, attach the event listener in `myfunction()`. Ajax is asynchronous, you have to wait for the request to complete.

Comment: `.blur` event on `td` how is it focussed? what do you have in`myfunction2`?

Comment: @Jai focused by mouse event, myfunction2 is a call to handle the edition of the td (which is, by the way, contenteditable="true").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the event listener after you insert the html on the callback.

```
<script>
function myfunction(result)
{
    $(".dyn").prop("innerHTML",result);
    $(".myeditable").on(blur,myfunction2);
}
</script>
```

Remember the call back function on $.post() will only execute when the data is received, asynchronously, so the line after $.post() will actually execute before the callback.

Comment: Not a good idea to bind event like this, if you run the function again there will be two bound events. XD

Comment: @Jai good point. will not happen in my case, but as a general answer your point is very important.